# Updating an old Ubuntu USB installer

Tags: system-installation, usb

I found an old USB stick that contains an Ubuntu 10.04 installer. I want to install Ubuntu on my Windows machine, but I want 12.04, not 10.04.

Can I update the USB stick to install 12.04, without wiping it out first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. Writing a new Ubuntu ISO to the flash drive will replace all content on the drive with the installer ISO data.